# Initialize Bootstrap colorpicker with mongoDB data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, color-picker

I have a meteor application and I added the plugin [colorpicker](https://github.com/itsjavi/bootstrap-colorpicker/) as a component.
But I want to initialize it with a value take in a MongoDB collection.
So I initialize the input text (something like `#32a214`) but I don't know how to initialize the color in the small square in the right.

In my html file I have :

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Color text image<br/></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
         <div id="colorText" class="input-group colorpicker-component">
            <input type="text" value={{textImageColor}} id="textImageColor" placeholder="Choose a color" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my javascript file, I have :

```
Template.yourTile.rendered = function(){

    $('#colorText').colorpicker({
        color: "#32a214"
    });
}
```

So I want to replace "#32a214" with a value from the database.
I would like to do something like that :

```
color: {{textImageColor}}
```

But it doesn't work.
So, do you know how I can do it ?

**EDIT :**

I have a javascript code on the server side :

```
Meteor.publish('tiles', function(){
  return tiles.find();
});
```

And I get the data with a helper :

```
Template.yourTile.helpers({
    'textImageColor': function(){
        var userID = Meteor.userId();
        var doc = tiles.findOne({createBy: userID });
        var textImageColor = doc && doc.textImageColor;
        if(textImageColor == ""){
            return "";
        }else{
            return textImageColor;
        }
    }
}
```

So if I call `{{textImageColor}}` in a html file, it works, but not in the javascript file.
I think it's maybe because the loading. The color is initialized in the rendered, so if I replace the color with `{{textImageColor}}` it doesn't work because the value is not yet load from the mongoDB collection. So maybe I need to wait to have the value but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: do you have any server code that is reading that value from the database and making it available via either a Meteor method or by publishing it?

Comment: I edit my question. So I have a server code which read the value from the database and publish it.
So like I said in the edit, maybe it's because the value is not yet load.
Do you know what I mean and how to do it ?

Comment: Do you have code on the client that subscribes to the data, and the same code on both the client and server that sets up the variable for the collection?

Comment: I have a subscription file with : `Meteor.subscribe('tiles');` and I set up the variable in the helper. All the code that I use is in the question and in the subscription file. I have nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

to do a successful pub/sub, you need all of the following:

1. collection with data in db
2. a collection definition common to the client and server code
3. a publisher on the server
4. a subscriber on the client
5. a find() on the client

it looks like you're missing #2.

in some common code (e.g. /collections/tiles.js), you need to define the collection. e.g.

```
tiles = new Mongo.Collection('tiles');
```

when run on the server, it will ensure that collection exists in the db. on the client, it will create a mini-mongo instance for that collection against which the client-side find() runs. it will also create a reference, "tiles", to those collections.

Comment: I have also this ! I forgot to put in the question but I have it in my code in collections/tilesDetails.js.
So, I don't think the problem come from this.

Comment: you can also install the meteor toys (https://atmospherejs.com/meteortoys/allthings) to see if your subscription is still active on the client. if not, then the client-side find() won't return anything.

Comment: So, like I said before, all the process which get the value from the database work. I think the problem was from the loading. It initialize the colorpicker before getting the value from the database. So, I changed the html code from the colorpicker plugin to pass the color  : `<span class="input-group-addon"><i style="background-color: {{textImageColor}};"></i></span>`.
So, now it works ! Thanks for your help !